# Creating concave hull with Python?

Tags: python, concave-hull

I'm trying to follow this tutoriel to do a concave hull script :
[Drawing Boundaries In Python](https://thehumangeo.wordpress.com/2014/05/12/drawing-boundaries-in-python/)

Of course, I drop all steps for plot results. But at the and of my script I have an error.
This is last lines :

```
edges = set()
edge_points = []

# loop over triangles:
# ia, ib, ic = indices of corner points of the triangle

for ia, ib, ic in tri.vertices:
    pa = coords[ia]
    pb = coords[ib]
    pc = coords[ic]
    # Lengths of sides of triangle
    a = math.sqrt((pa[0]-pb[0])**2 + (pa[1]-pb[1])**2)
    b = math.sqrt((pb[0]-pc[0])**2 + (pb[1]-pc[1])**2)
    c = math.sqrt((pc[0]-pa[0])**2 + (pc[1]-pa[1])**2)
    # Semiperimeter of triangle
    s = (a + b + c)/2.0
    # Area of triangle by Heron's formula
    area = math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
    circum_r = a*b*c/(4.0*area)
    # Here's the radius filter.
    #print circum_r
    if circum_r < 1.0/alpha:
        add_edge(edges, edge_points, coords, ia, ib)
        add_edge(edges, edge_points, coords, ib, ic)
        add_edge(edges, edge_points, coords, ic, ia)

m = geometry.MultiLineString(edge_points)
triangles = list(polygonize(m))
return cascaded_union(triangles), edge_points
```

And it returns :

```
Assertion failed: (!static_cast<bool>("should never be reached")),
function itemsTree, file AbstractSTRtree.cpp, line 373.
Abort trap: 6
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Which line exactly triggers that? Do you use a spatial index?

Comment: The last line is generating this error and more precisely, cascaded_union() fonction... For spatial index, I don't think so.

Comment: Seems like a bug! Please see https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/search?q=AbstractSTRtree.cpp&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93 and try if updating accordingly fixes it. If not, please try to make a bug report with the data that leads to this. :) If this fixes it, please post that as your own answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it's said [here](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/553) in Workaround 2, you have to  import shapely first and fiona after.

For me it solves issue.